# Install rstudio-server failed in a docker container based on centos 7

Tags: centos, docker, rstudio

I think this is the correct place to post this question.
I am using Dockerfile to build the Rstudio development environment.

```
FROM rstudio/r-base:devel-centos7 AS base
RUN wget https://download2.rstudio.org/server/centos6/x86_64/rstudio-server-rhel-1.3.959-x86_64.rpm
RUN yum install rstudio-server-rhel-1.3.959-x86_64.rpm
CMD ["bash"]
```

I create a folder /home/myname/r_setup, cd to this folder, create Dockerfile with above content into it and build the image using: `docker build -t temp:rstudio .`

Then I use `docker run -it temp:rstudio bash` to start it and get access into the container

Although I could see the rstudio-server already installed, but neither `rstudio-server start` nor `systemctl start rstudio-server` works.

The error message said: `"/etc/init.d/rstudio-server line8: /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions no such file"`

Does anyone knows what happened?

I have post this in R posit forum,but after weeks no one answers. So I post this here to see if someone knows what is the problem and how to fix it.